# Rails Axlsx New Line in Cell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axlsx

Is there a way that I can add a new line to a cell using the Axlsx gem in Rails?

So basically replicating in Excel once you enter a value you can do a Alt + Enter to add additional text to the new line in the cell. I tried

```
sheet.add_row ["Testing cell row 1" + \r\n + "Testing cell row 2"]
```

but that throws an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a forced line feed use "\x0A" (breaks between paragraphs.)

If you want both carriage return and line feed, use "\x0D\x0A".

Answer (score 12):

I recently had the same problem and I found a solution that works.

I used this to setup:

```
p = Axlsx::Package.new
p.use_shared_strings = true
```

And this code adds a `wrap` style that makes the `\r` line breaks work correctly:

```
wrap = p.workbook.styles.add_style alignment: {wrap_text: true}
sheet.add_row "1\r2\r3", style: wrap
```

Now the new line in cell works, and the output is:

```
1
2
3
```

Notes:

- The new line in cell doesn't work (@Gary Pinkham)
- The `"\x0D\x0A"` didn't work (@noel)

Comment: for me the `style: wrap` work together with `\n` (on Windows)

Comment: This solved my problem! I also added "\x0A" between the strings as the answer below mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't comment on the "doesn't work in mac excel" comment so adding this as an answer..    use package.use_shared_strings = true..   needed for Mac Excel..