# Ruby Axlsx add new line to cell in whatever OS

Tags: ruby, excel, axlsx

the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770025/rails-axlsx-new-line-in-cell) doesn't  work for excel in  mac osx, 
I have tried:

```
sheet.add_row ["row1 \r\n\x0D\x0A row2"]
```

still doesn't work

Comment: Did you try different reader? I just have the same problem with Win7. With Excel the file has no line break, with OpenOffice I get the line breaks.

Comment: I used other api to achieve it in Excel